T-SQL ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE key derivation procedure
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE in T-SQL takes a passphrase as a parameter. I'm wanting to encrypt some data in the same way outside of SQL server, in such a way as said data may be decrypted using the DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE function once ingested into SQL Server.
I can't however find any reference to how SQL Server (>= 2017) derives the key from the passphrase.
Does anyone know how this is done (e.g. using PBKDF2, what salt, how many iterations)? or where I can easily find this info?

Doesn't it say so on the tin? SQL Server 2017 and later versions encrypts data with a passphrase using an AES256 key

@siggemannen But it doesn't say how it derives that key. There are many KDFs, each of which can have different parameters.

Hmm, i guess so, @Charlieface, but i'm guessing it doesn't do any derivations so there's no point of mentioning it? But this looks promising anyway: https://github.com/krcs/SQLServerCrypto

@siggemannen Yes appears to be SHA256 hashing. But in the actual ancryption part, there are also some magic numbers involved and a bunch of other stuff with headers and what not.

@Charlieface yeah, true, perhaps one should add a note for microsoft to document the algo. It doesn't seem to be secure enough for anything serious though, at least i wouldn't use it for password hashing

@siggemannen You can make a pull request https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql.md
